# How can I debug my C++ dll project that call by Third-Party application?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, dll

**Hello.
I have an Third-Party application (i haven't it's source code, i have it's .exe file only) and i was created a C++ solution that contains 1 .exe project and 2 .dll projects in Visual Studio 2015.

That Third-Party application is using these 3 files to execute.

Now, i have a logical error in a function in one of my 3 files and i use to debug it, but when i put breakpoint and start debugging, the breakpiont not hit and no symbol load for it, while that function is calling by the Third-Party application and i'm sure about this.

All of my files have .pdb file and i put them in the same location with the Third-Party .exe file, but i can't debug it! Also i add the .pdb files (my files) path into Tools\Options\Debugging\Symbols\Symbol file (.pdb) locations, but it doesn't have effect.

Please help me, Thanks ...

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a small executable that calls your code and debug from there?

Comment: Do you get warnings about your symbols not loading for your dll?

Comment: Is the third party application C++ too? Do you have a debug compilation of that app? Usually you cannot link debug libs with a release program, so i'm wondering what you are actually doing.
You don't need to add pdb manually anywhere, VisualStudio should find them on its own. Something else is wrong.

Too much info missing about the setup. 

Do you have optimizations on? The line you want to break might actually be optimized away... Many possibilites.

Comment: @lars: PDB files can also be generated for release builds, which makes it a lot easier to debug them.

Comment: " when i put breakpoint and start debugging". Start debugging _which project_? If you debug your executable project, you're probably not debugging the third-party application. Also, do I understand correctly that the third-party exe is starting your exe? Which of the two exe's is loading the DLL's?

Comment: @MSalters Ofcourse, but stepping through code in release builds is often a nightmare.

Comment: Sorry for delay.

Comment: @lars: Sorry for delay. Third-Application is C++ too. What is debug compilation ? Optimization option is set with "Full Optimization (/Ox) .

Comment: @MSalters: I want to debug my own project (.dll), not the Third-Party project. Exactly, the Third-Party application that i just have its .exe file needs my 3 project files to execute.

Comment: @MSalters: I don't know exactly which .exe loading the dll's, my project .exe or the Third-Party application .exe! I just know that the Third-Party application don't execute without my 3 projects files.

Comment: No one else has an idea?